# v4l2-ctl - Video length and stream count

Tags: linux, v4l2

I am trying to record a 15 seconds video using v4l2-ctl but I got a bit confused with its parameters, even after looking for articles on the Internet.

```
v4l2-ctl --set-fmt-video=width=960,height=720,pixelformat=1
v4l2-ctl --stream-mmap=3 --stream-count=100 --stream-to=$1
```

How do I set the video length?
What exactly does the `--stream-count` mean?

Answer (score 4):

from `v4l2-ctl --help-streaming`:

> `--stream-count=<count>` stream <count> buffers. The default is to keep streaming
>   forever. This count does not include the number of initial
>   skipped buffers as is passed by --stream-skip.

so the `--stream-count` can be used to set the number of frames to capture.