# v4l2-ctl - set video length in seconds

Tags: v4l2, uvc, uvcvideo

How I can set video length?
In my example

```
v4l2-ctl --verbose -d 0 --set-fmt-video=width=1280,height=720,pixelformat=MJPG --stream-mmap --set-parm 25 --stream-to=video.yuvj422p --stream-count=100
```

I can set **max** framerate

```
--set-parm 25
```

I can set frames amount.

```
--stream-count=100
```

And it will [not works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628812/v4l2-ctl-video-length-and-stream-count)... Because camera can decide change my framerate to less value because of not enough light. For dark environment camera can decide not 25 fps but 7.5 fps. But I want 15 seconds video. How set video length in seconds?